# How insert the contact info on the existing contact in Android 1.6?

Tags: android, android-intent, contacts

I have name, phone number and E-mail infomation of a contact. I just want to insert the additional email and phone for the existing contact. My questions are

1. How to find the contact is already existing or not?
2. How to insert the values on the additional or secondary address option?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you should modify your problem description pointing to target device is API Level 4.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the official document has new contancts api.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html

First, look up raw contacts id with your criteria, such as name:

```
final String name = "reader";
// find "reader"'s contact 
String select = String.format("%s=? AND %s='%s'", 
        Data.DISPLAY_NAME, Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
String[] project = new String[] { Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID };
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
        Data.CONTENT_URI, project, select, new String[] { name }, null);

long rawContactId = -1;
if(c.moveToFirst()){
    rawContactId = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID));
}
c.close();
```

Second, use rawContactId to add an entry to contacts:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId);
values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
values.put(Phone.NUMBER, "1-800-GOOG-411");
values.put(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_CUSTOM);
values.put(Phone.LABEL, "free directory assistance");
Uri dataUri = getContentResolver().insert(Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

PS. don't forget the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: I am working on API Level 4. But this api available on API level 5. is there any other way to do it?

Comment: there is nothing to check whether to check a contact is existing or not.

Comment: Cursor is the result set. Not existing when nothing in the result ( the count of cursor is zero)

Comment: what is the rawContactId,how to get the value for that? whatever i save becomes an invisible contacts!

Comment: how do i add contact as Favourite contacts?