# Android insert contact not showing name

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts

I am trying to export contact from my application to the Android's default contact list. I am using an intent to insert the contact details by launching the contact activity. The contact activity pre-populate most of the intent data in the form, but It is not able to populate the name of the contact. Here is my code for populating the intent data.

```
ArrayList<ContentValues> data = new ArrayList<>();

        if (!contactDetails.getName().isEmpty()) {
            ContentValues rowName = new ContentValues();
            rowName.put(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
            rowName.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, contactDetails.getName());
            data.add(rowName);
        }
        if (!contactDetails.getCompany().isEmpty()) {
            ContentValues rowCompany = new ContentValues();
            rowCompany.put(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
            rowCompany.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.COMPANY, contactDetails.getCompany());
            data.add(rowCompany);

        }

        if (!contactDetails.getPhone().isEmpty()) {
            ContentValues rowPhone = new ContentValues();
            rowPhone.put(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
            rowPhone.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, contactDetails.getPhone());
            data.add(rowPhone);
        }

        ContentValues rowEmail = new ContentValues();
        rowEmail.put(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        rowEmail.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_MOBILE);
        rowEmail.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.LABEL, "Work");
        rowEmail.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS, contactDetails.getEmail());
        data.add(rowEmail);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.DATA, data);

        startActivity(intent);
```

Here is the screen shot. Notice that the name field is empty, even when intent has the data.

[image: Contact insert activity]

I feel that I am not providing the right value for the following lines.

```
rowName.put(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
                rowName.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, contactDetails.getName());
```

I tried the NickName field and it does work. example code.

```
if (!contactDetails.getName().isEmpty()) {
            ContentValues rowName = new ContentValues();
            rowName.put(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Nickname.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
            rowName.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Nickname.NAME, contactDetails.getName());
            data.add(rowName);
        }
```

But not sure why it is not able to successfully display the name. Am i missing something here?

Comment: are you testing ur app on 4.0 ? try to check ur app in to another device .may be that's the reason . refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32043971/insert-contact-programmatically-in-android-4-0-is-not-showing-in-default-contact .

Comment: Thanks for you response. I am testing it on 6.0.

Comment: are you getting ur name in logcat ?? plz refer this , may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045458/how-insert-the-contact-info-on-the-existing-contact-in-android-1-6

Comment: When I run the application in debug mode. I do see that the name is places inside the intent. Do you mean I am passing empty string in name field? I had check and I am not passing empty string in name field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this problem by just adding the following line just before `startActivity()` method call.

```
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, contactDetails.getName());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this its working for me ,and let me inform if you are facing still any issue .Here there are five fields for user to insert data , you can modify this as per ur need.

This is for **adding new contact**

```
   // Creating a button click listener for the "Add Contact" button
    OnClickListener addClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Getting reference to Name EditText 
            EditText etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_name);

            // Getting reference to Mobile EditText 
            EditText etMobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_mobile_phone);

            // Getting reference to HomePhone EditText 
            EditText etHomePhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_home_phone);

            // Getting reference to HomeEmail EditText 
            EditText etHomeEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_home_email);

            // Getting reference to WorkEmail EditText 
            EditText etWorkEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_work_email);             

            ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops =
                      new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

            int rawContactID = ops.size();

            // Adding insert operation to operations list 
            // to insert a new raw contact in the table ContactsContract.RawContacts
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
                    .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
                    .build());

            // Adding insert operation to operations list
            // to insert display name in the table ContactsContract.Data
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, etName.getText().toString())
                    .build());

            // Adding insert operation to operations list
            // to insert Mobile Number in the table ContactsContract.Data
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, etMobile.getText().toString())
                    .withValue(Phone.TYPE, CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
                    .build());

            // Adding insert operation to operations list
            // to  insert Home Phone Number in the table ContactsContract.Data
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, etHomePhone.getText().toString())
                    .withValue(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_HOME)
                    .build());

            // Adding insert operation to operations list
            // to insert Home Email in the table ContactsContract.Data
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(Email.ADDRESS, etHomeEmail.getText().toString())
                    .withValue(Email.TYPE, Email.TYPE_HOME)
                    .build());

            // Adding insert operation to operations list
            // to insert Work Email in the table ContactsContract.Data
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(Email.ADDRESS, etWorkEmail.getText().toString())
                    .withValue(Email.TYPE, Email.TYPE_WORK)
                    .build());              

            try{
                // Executing all the insert operations as a single database transaction
                getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Contact is successfully added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }catch (RemoteException e) {                    
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

This is for display **contact list**

```
OnClickListener contactsClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Creating an intent to open Android's Contacts List
            Intent contacts = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);

            // Starting the activity
            startActivity(contacts);                
        }
    };
```

This are the permissions you need to set in side **Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cursor to fetch contacts from device.

```
public void fetchContacts() {

    String phoneNumber = null;
    String email = null;

    Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String _ID = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID;
    String DISPLAY_NAME = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;
    String HAS_PHONE_NUMBER = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;

    Uri PhoneCONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
    String Phone_CONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID;
    String NUMBER = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;

    Uri EmailCONTENT_URI =  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI;
    String EmailCONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID;
    String DATA = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA;

    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);  

    // Loop for every contact in the phone
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            String contact_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( _ID ));
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( DISPLAY_NAME ));

            int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( HAS_PHONE_NUMBER )));

            if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {

                output.append("\n First Name:" + name);

                // Query and loop for every phone number of the contact
                Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(PhoneCONTENT_URI, null, Phone_CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { contact_id }, null);

                while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                    phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(NUMBER));
                    output.append("\n Phone number:" + phoneNumber);

                }

                phoneCursor.close();

                // Query and loop for every email of the contact
                Cursor emailCursor = contentResolver.query(EmailCONTENT_URI,    null, EmailCONTACT_ID+ " = ?", new String[] { contact_id }, null);

                while (emailCursor.moveToNext()) {

                    email = emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(DATA));

                    output.append("\nEmail:" + email);

                }

                emailCursor.close();
            }

            output.append("\n");
        }

         System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```